# Is it possible to display numbers as hex in Remix?

Tags: remix

I'm using a fixed-point math library that works with binary numbers, so values like 0x10000000000000000 are assumed to be 1.

I implemented a function that raises a given number to a given power. Raising 0x10000000000000000 to the power of 2 yields the same number:

[image: Remix Caption]

I would prefer the result to show up as 0x10000000000000000 rather than 18446744073709551616, the latter being of course the former converted to decimal. Can I make Remix display numbers as hex?

My function:

```
function doPow(int128 x, uint256 y) external pure returns (int128) {
    return ABDKMath64x64.pow(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried returning a `bytes memory` instead of an integer? I've tested a simple function that returns `bytes` and it seems to work as you want, but I'm not sure since you're working with binary numbers. To clarify, I'm using `abi.encodePacked`.

Comment: Thanks, Alberto! I added an answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: I just discovered this [number converter](https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/math#convert-number) tool developed ABDK, the same guys who developed the `ABDKMath64x64` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @alberto's suggestion in the comment, I changed the return type from `int128` to `bytes memory` and re-wrote my function like this:

```
function doPow(int128 x, uint256 y) external pure returns (bytes memory) {
    int128 result = ABDKMath64x64.pow(x, y);
    bytes memory encodedResult = abi.encodePacked(result);
    return encodedResult;
}
```

Now the result shows up like this:

[image: Remix Caption]